# ggplot2: A mean row in heatmaps

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

Say I created a heatmap using the function `geom_raster()` (from `ggplot2`).

What's a smart way to add a row at the bottom of the table showing (in my case) the 'Mean return' for each month on the period considered ?

It would be nice there is some space left between the 1985-2013 period and the row for the average, and maybe police color and 'cases' could be customized.

The core of my code is as follows (the object `molten` contains the my data, originally a matrix passed through the `melt()` function of `reshape2`.

```
hm <- ggplot(data = molten, aes(x = factor(Var2, levels = month.abb), y=Var1, fillll=value)) + geom_raster()
hm <- hm + scale_fill_gradient2(low=LtoM(100), mid=Mid, high=MtoH(100))
hm <- hm + labs(fill='% Return')
hm <- hm + geom_text(aes(label=paste(sprintf("%.1f %%", value))), size = 4)
hm <- hm + scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1985:2013)
hm <- hm + xlab(label = NULL) + ylab(label = NULL)
hm <- hm + theme_bw()
hm <- hm + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0, vjust = 0.4, angle=90))
```

[image]

Comment: You do not need to add `hm <- hm + ` constantly, simply append a `+` at the end of each line and continue on the next line. R will pick this up correctly.

Comment: If you can use data that we can reproduce the problem it's helpful.  We don't have `molten` so help is more difficult.  Programming is often a hands on type of solving process and not being able to use the code you give makes helping a chore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

I created a grid to mock up your data

Main changes, are to precalculate the aggregate and "spacer" data rows, and add to molten, 
then add scale_y_discrete so you can label the rows, 
then make sure the format works for the grey spacer bar with no % label (comments in code)

Easier in future if you include the data (or a sample) in the question

[image: plot]

```
require(ggplot2)

molten<-expand.grid(c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"),1985:2013,0)
colnames(molten)<-c("Var2","Var1","value")
molten$value=(runif(nrow(molten))*60)-30

#create means
means<-aggregate(molten[,c(1,3)], by=list(molten$Var2),FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
colnames(means)<-c("Var2","Var1","value")
means$Var1<-"MEANS"

#create spacer bar
spacer<-means
spacer$Var1<-" "
spacer$value<-NA

#append them to the data
molten<-rbind(molten,spacer,means)


hm <- ggplot(data = molten, aes(x = Var2, y=Var1, fill=value)) + 
geom_raster() +
# replaced your functions for ease of use
scale_fill_gradient2(low="red", mid="yellow", high="green",na.value="grey") +
labs(fill='% Return') +
# don't format the NA vals with %, return blank
geom_text(aes(label=ifelse((is.na(value)),"",paste(sprintf("%.1f %%", value)))), size = 4) +
# make the scale discrete to add labels and enforce order (use a blank space for the spacer)
scale_y_discrete(limits = c("MEANS"," ",1985:2013)) +
xlab(label = NULL) + ylab(label = NULL) +
theme_bw() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0, vjust = 0.4, angle=90))

hm
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not very concise, but I think this should do what you need.

You didn't provide a data set, so I just made some up. Also, the `LtoM` and `MtoH` functions are not included in any R package I could find, so I did a quick Google search and found them [here](http://quantcorner.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/creating-a-heatmap-to-visualize-returns-with-r-ggplot2/)

The following code produces a plot `hm2` with facets to make the "Mean Return" row at the bottom:

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)

# Random data
set.seed(100)
casted = data.frame(Var1 = rep(1985:2013, times=12), Var2 = rep(month.abb, each=29), return = rnorm(12*29, 0, 9))
molten = melt(casted, id.vars = c("Var1", "Var2"))

LtoM <-colorRampPalette(c('red', 'yellow' ))
Mid <- "snow3"
MtoH <-colorRampPalette(c('lightgreen', 'darkgreen'))

# Averages
monthly.avg = cbind(Var1 = rep("Mean", 12), dcast(molten, Var2 ~ ., mean))
colnames(monthly.avg)[3] = "Mean"
molten2 = merge(molten, melt(monthly.avg), all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)

# New plot
hm2 = 
  ggplot(data = molten2, aes(x = factor(Var2, levels = month.abb), y=Var1, fill=value)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low=LtoM(100), mid=Mid, high=MtoH(100)) +
  labs(fill='% Return') +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(sprintf("%.1f %%", value))), size = 4) +
  xlab(label = NULL) + ylab(label = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0, vjust = 0.4, angle=90)) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y") +    # grid layout
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour = 'NA', fill = 'NA'), strip.text.y = element_text(colour = 'white'))    # remove facet labels
```

which gives the following plot:

[image: Plot with Mean Row]